# Exclude certain values in ManytoOne Array Colletion/Formbuilder

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I am having trouble getting a formular in Symfony2 where I want to exclude certain values within an array collection - or I have to say I don't know how (where to exclude them).

This is my newTag Action:

```
public function newTagAction()
{
    $tag = new Tag();
    $form = $this->createForm(new tagType(), $tag);
    return $this->render('MyMyBundle:Admin:newTag.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

And Tag.php Entity, which has a ManyToOne relation to Movie and vice verca (Movie->Tag = OneToMany):

```
class Tag
{

/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movie", inversedBy="videotags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $movie;

// ...
```

In the TagType.php form it says:

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('movie') // This is where certain movies should be excluded, it displays an array collection of all movies 
    ;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom queries to get only the results you want.

It's explained in the [documents](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities). Here is a quick example:

```
$builder->add('movie', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyMovieBundle:Movie',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.name = ?1');
    },
));
```

Comment: Hi Hakan, first many thanks for you answer! I just added the lines above and it comes with "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to My\MyBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of My\MyBundle\Form\EntityRepository, instance of ME\MEBundle\Repository\MovieRepository given ... Do I have to add the namespaces?

Comment: nevermind... use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; :-) Many THANKS! +1